# Pegar valor de uma TD de uma tabela HTML para alimentar uma variável PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, variáveis, tabela-html

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema web. Neste sistema tenho tabelas com muitas colunas já que são muitas informações, para reduzir isso eu selecionei as informações mais importantes a serem exibidas e coloquei nessa tabela, porém se o usuário necessitar consultar TODAS as informações, eu preciso ter essa opção para ele, para isso eu queria pegar o código que está em uma td dessa tabela parar usar como parâmetro de restrição na hora fazer o select que vai exibir todas as informações de determinado funcionário por exemplo.

**Código Tabela**

```
                     
                         $result_funcionario =  "SELECT * FROM tb_funcionarios";
                         $resultado_funcionario = mysqli_query($con, $result_funcionario);
                    

                    ?>


                
                     
                

                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered"  id="hidden-table-info">
                    <thead >
                      <tr>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th >Código</th>
                        <th class="">Nome</th>
                        <th class="-">CPF</th>
                        <th class="">RG</th>
                        <th class="">Celular</th>   
                        <th class="">Salário</th>                       
                        <th class="">Situação</th>                      
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                 
                 
                     <?php while ($row_funcionario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_funcionario)) { ?>
          
                 
               
                      <tr class="">
                        <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
                        <td class="" name="codigo_func"><?php echo $row_funcionario ["codigo_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class="" name="nome_func"><?php echo $row_funcionario ["nome_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["cpf_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["rg_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["celular_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["salario_funcionario"];   ?></td>                       
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["situacao_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                      </tr>

              


                        <?php   } ?>
```

No caso, eu preciso pegar o valor contido dentro da td nome_func para que na página textex.php eu consiga exibir os valores a respeito só do funcionario que eu captar o id

Comment: vai precisar usar jquery

Comment: Caso haja uma resposta que resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita, veja como https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Vai precisar de Jquery

**Comentários no código**

1. Enviando por um form via POST

   Eu coloquei para pegar o valor contido dentro da td `codigo_func` por achar mais correto porque pode existir nomes iguais. Mas se quiser preferir pegar o valor contido dentro da td `nome_func` faça as alterações:

   - `.find('td.codigo_func') por .find('td.nome_func')`
   - `<td class="" name="nome_func">  por <td class="nome_func" name="nome_func">`

```js
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {   
      //$('#hidden-table-info').find('td.codigo_func') vai encontrar todas as tds cuja classe é codigo_func
      $('#hidden-table-info').find('td.codigo_func').each(function ()
      {
        $(this).click(function ()
        {
           var tdValue = $(this).html(); //texto da td clicada
           // o input que vai receber essa variável como value
           document.getElementById("codFun").value = tdValue;
           
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered"  id="hidden-table-info">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th >Codigo</th>
            <th class="">Nome</th>
            <th class="-">CPF</th>
            <th class="">Email</th>
            <th class="">Celular</th>                       
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                        
        <!-- ## Exemplo gerado pelo while do PHP ## -->               
                         
                       
        <tr class="">
            <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
            <td class="codigo_func" name="codigo_func">123</td>
            <td class="" name="nome_func">Leo</td>
            <td class="">111.222.333-01</td>
            <td class="">leo@email.com.br</td>
            <td class="">23344559</td>
        </tr>
               
        <tr class="">
            <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
            <td class="codigo_func" name="codigo_func">124</td>
            <td class="" name="nome_func">Alicia</td>
            <td class="">000.000.002-02</td>
            <td class="">alicia@email.com.br</td>
            <td class="">22433443</td>
        </tr>
               
        <tr class="">
            <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
            <td class="codigo_func" name="codigo_func">125</td>
            <td class="" name="nome_func">Samuel</td>
            <td class="">222.000.444-03</td>
            <td class="">samuel@email.com.br</td>
            <td class="">45678998</td>
        </tr>
               
        <tr class="">
            <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
            <td class="codigo_func" name="codigo_func">128</td>
            <td class="" name="nome_func">Ciclano</td>
            <td class="">903.904.905-06</td>
            <td class="">ciclano@email.com.br</td>
            <td class="">76543787</td>
        </tr>
               
        <tr class="">
            <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
            <td class="codigo_func" name="codigo_func">129</td>
            <td class="" name="nome_func">Athena</td>
            <td class="">456.765.345-00</td>
            <td class="">athena@email.com.br</td>
            <td class="">5678907</td>
        </tr>
                                       
        <tr class="">
            <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
            <td class="codigo_func" name="codigo_func">130</td>
            <td class="" name="nome_func">Maria</td>
            <td class="">325.627.423-87</td>
            <td class="">maria@email.com.br</td>
            <td class="">7654321</td>
        </tr>
           
        <tr class="">
            <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
            <td class="codigo_func" name="codigo_func">131</td>
            <td class="" name="nome_func">Fernanda</td>
            <td class="">567.765.567-76</td>
            <td class="">fernanda@email.com.br</td>
            <td class="">8765438</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <!-- ##### Supondo que será enviado por um form via POST #### -->
    
    <!-- ## Elemento que vai receber como value a variável do JavaScript ## -->  
  
    <input type="txt" name="" id="codFun" value="">
```

2. Via GET - modificações no código

   Script

   ```
       $(document).ready(function ()
       {   

         $('#hidden-table-info').find('a.codigo_func').each(function ()
         {
           $(this).click(function ()
           {
              var aValue = $(this).html();
              $(".codigo_func").attr("href", "testex.php?codFun="+aValue);

           });
         });
       });
   ```

   HTML

   ```
   <tr class="">
       <td class=""><a href=""><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
       <td class="" name="codigo_func"><a href="" class="codigo_func"><?php echo $row_funcionario ["id"];   ?></a></td>
       <td class="" name="nome_func"><?php echo $row_funcionario ["nome"];   ?></td>
       <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["cpf"];   ?></td>
       <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["email"];   ?></td>
       <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["telefone"];   ?></td>
   </tr>
   ```

Comment: A metodologia do get eu entendi e consegui colocar em prática, porem pra mim o POST é mais interessante, no entanto não consegui compreender para colocar em prática, pode me explicar como que o input vai receber o valor clicado? onde será o click? Agradecido desde já.

Comment: $(this).click(function () é uma função sobre a td clicada e essa função vai criar uma variável cujo valor é o texto da td clicada.

Comment: No exemplo que coloquei acima (POST)  o clique é nos códigos ( 123 - 124 -125 etc.. ) Mas se você adaptar o código para os nomes, então vai ter que clicar nos nomes.

Comment: O value do input vai ser enviado via post para a pagina PHP desde que esteja incluído em um formulário.

Answer (score 0):

dependendo da situação da pra passar via get.

```html
                     <?php while ($row_funcionario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_funcionario)) { 
                        $nome = $row_funcionario ["nome_funcionario"]; ?>
                         
                        
                 
               
                      <tr class="">
                        <td class=""><a href="testex.php"><img src="lib/advanced-datatable/images/details_open.png"></a></td>
                        <td class="" name="codigo_func"><?php echo $row_funcionario ["codigo_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class="" name="nome_func"> <a href="textex.php?nome=<?=$nome?>"></a></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["cpf_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["rg_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["celular_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["salario_funcionario"];   ?></td>                       
                        <td class=""><?php echo $row_funcionario ["situacao_funcionario"];   ?></td>
                      </tr>

              


                        <?php   } ?>
```

Comment: Poderia me exemplificar a forma que posso usar o GET Samuel, to quebrando cabeça e não consigo encaixar. Agradeço pela atenção

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=6cIBQGV8-mI           neste video vc vai encontrar um pouco sovre get, como passar o valor e como pegal-lo da url. Seria bob que se aprofundasse nos metodos GET e POST, vai presisar muito deles para programar.